# How to open two same Winforms on Maximised and minimized WindowState?

Tags: c#

I have an game as an Winform in Full Screen (no borders), maximized. But I want to present them on an different screen, like a beamer and control it on the original screen, so I need the same screen, opened twice:

- One at my own screen Maximized, no borders
- One at the second screen, normal state with title bar.

I'm quite sure, I'm thinking about this too easily. What I tried is:

```
new game().Show();
new game().Show(WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal));
```

But then It says:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState' to 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window'

So, is this hard to do?

Comment: Creating two instances of your game-form will only work if you game-form-instance doesn't contain any state. Otherwise any actions you do in one game-form-instance won't be reflected in the other game-form-instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
game g1 = new game();
g1.Show();
game g2 = new game();
g2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
g2.Show();
```

What you tried doesn't work because `Form.Show()` expects either nothing or another `IWin32Window` (typically another `Form`) as an argument, and you're passing a `FormWindowState`.

Note that, while this shows you how to open two forms of the same class with different window states, it doesn't show you how to make two different forms show the same game content at once, which will be much more involved.

Comment: Cool, that worked perfect! And how could I add the titlebar? Just set that at true?

Comment: I would assume so.

Comment: Fixed, added g2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;